# Any standard techniques, mechanisms,tools for generating exceptions for use with test code to thoroughly test C++?

Tags: c++, exception, testing

With Symbian's version of C++ it is possible to precisely control simulation of low memory conditions and thus deterministically generate a leave (a leave is Symbian C++'s equivalent to a throw) for all possible combinations of execution paths through your code based on allocation failure.

This is incredibly useful for testing purposes, as the vast majority of leaves/exceptions within Symbian (i.e. on a constrained device) are as a consequence of low memory, it effectively means you can thoroughly test your code for exception safety. This invariably reveals many, many defects, including many not related to exception handling.

For those of you who have a copy of Exceptional C++ to hand, refer to item 18 - imagine being able to generate conditions quite easily to test all 23 paths of execution through that code and the consequent benefit that has.

So my question is, are there any mechanisms or techniques or tools that will enable you within test code to generate exceptions to thoroughly test the exception handling of code?

Suppose you had to white box test the code in item 18 of Exceptional C++ (and please lets not get into discussions saying the code should be re-written, suppose it can't be) how could you test it to ensure all 23 paths of execution are being executed within test code?

---

This question is not about Symbian, I use use it to provide some context to illustrate from experience the incredible benefit of being able to deterministically control the generation of exceptions for testing purposes, and thus wondering how to achieve the same in standard C++.

Comment: I don't know anything about the Symbian stuff.  How do you express the notion that a particular function call on a particular line of source code should fail (i.e. throw), whilst still having a maintainable unit test that isn't full of brittle insider knowledge?

Comment: They use a naming convention which must be adherred to - functions that can "throw" are named with a trailing L in their name. And new is overloaded so it looks like "new (ELeave) T" which would result in an exception being thrown if the new can't succeed (calling new without (ELeave) is not permitted)

Comment: I see.  But how does your unit test trigger a *particular* `new` to fail?

Comment: In debug builds the Symbian heap allocation code can be controlled so that it will fail at an Nth allocation. This is done using a macro like __FAIL_NEXT(N). Thus you can specify N to achieve a particular failure. But that's not very useful, what is is testing using a loop starting at 1 and incrementing N each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace global operator new, so any allocation that goes through that now goes through your code. Then in that code, do whatever it is you want to control when allocation fails and an exception is thrown. The only strategy I've actually used is a simple counter in the allocator. First run the code such that the first allocation it makes will fail, then re-run with the second allocation failing, etc until the code under test completes without the counter reaching the value that would trigger the manufactured failure. At each step, check for memory leaks and do any other tests you have for the consistency of structures.

Comment: To complement your answer:

That's exactly how Symbian's Out-of-memory test harness works. In other words there's nothing special about Symbian's leave mechanism - it does not add testability as such, but it lacks type safety, and polymorphism from the standard C++ exception mechanism.

Comment: Any mechanisms for generalizing, to deal with other classes of exception beyond memory related ones?

Comment: @David: well, replacing operator new is (in effect) faking/mocking the memory allocator. In general, for other kinds of exceptions you need to fake whatever throws the exception. This is *much* easier if you can design the code under test to use dependency injection in the first place, but for example if you need to fake a network interface and can't change the code under test, you might still be able to mess about with header files and/or libraries linked against, to slide in a wrapper layer.